# MonoDevelop Not Recognizing .NET 4.5 Support

Tags: frameworks, f#, mono, monodevelop, .net-4.5

I have recently installed both Mono (3.0.8) and MonoDevelop (4.0) on my linux machine (Arch linux).  I have a Solution that contains a number of projects that depend on the .NET 4.5 Framework.  (Specifically, I'm working with the [Casanova project](http://casanova.codeplex.com/))  However, MonoDevelop does not seem to recognize the .NET 4.5 framework for projects; it only recognizes .NET 4.0 and prior as a target framework.

[image: MonoDevelop Build Settings]

I know Mono 3.0.8 supports basic .NET 4.5, but I'm not sure why MonoDevelop cannot see this.  When I create a project as Mono / .NET 4.0 and attempt to build it, it fails to find definitions for .NET 4.5 specific fields and members.  Is there a way I can force MonoDevelop to read in .NET 4.5 projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have built Mono and MonoDevelop from Github sources and it seems to have some .NET 4.5 support:
[image]

Not sure what about F#, I wasn't able to install F# addon yet.

The Mono version from Github master branch is **Mono 3.0.4** (master/b23a610 Thu Mar  7 20:47:00 MSK 2013) for me, not 3.0.8.

Comment: wrong, master branch is 3.0.8: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/configure.in

Comment: I pulled from the master branch and remade, and found Mono / .NET 4.5.  Thanks!